# Aggregating multiple gradle java project test results without using the "reportOn" method

Tags: java, gradle, gradle-plugin, gradlew

We have a multiple gradle java project.
This project exports aggregated test report when "gradlew testReport" command executes.

We use "reportOn" method but this method is deprecated, so this warning log is output to the console.

> The TestReport.reportOn(Object...) method has been deprecated. This is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 8.0. Please use the testResults method instead. See https://docs.gradle.org/7.5.1/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.TestReport.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.TestReport:testResults for more details.

We have rewritten the configuration referring to the link in the warning log, but it did not work.
We would like to achieve the same behavior without using the "reportOn" method.

---

Our project structure like this.

```
root
 |--- buildSrc
 |--- batch
 |--- common
 |--- webapp
 |--- webservice
```

And each `build.gradle` like this.

root\buildSrc\src\main\groovy\java-common.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'eclipse'
    id 'project-report'
    id 'org.springframework.boot'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management'
}

sourceCompatibility = 17
targetCompatibility = 17

[compileJava, compileTestJava]*.options*.encoding = "UTF-8"

group = 'com.example'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
    testCompileOnly {
        extendsFrom testAnnotationProcessor
    }
}

dependencies {
    // Spring
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    
    // Apache Commons Lang3
    implementation "org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.12.0"
    
    // lombok
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testCompileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testAnnotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'

    // JUnit
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.9.1'
    
    // Mockito
    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:4.8.1'
    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-inline:4.8.1'
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()

    testLogging {
        showStandardStreams false
        events 'failed'
        exceptionFormat 'full'
    }
    systemProperty "file.encoding", "UTF-8"
    jvmArgs = ['--add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED']
}

test {
    // Test Result Reports are output from all projects at once.
    reports.html.required = false
}

// Create a Test Result Report
// gradlew testReport
task testReport(type: TestReport) {
    destinationDirectory = file("${rootDir}/build/reports/allTests")
    reportOn files("${rootDir}/batch/build/test-results/test/binary",
        "${rootDir}/common/build/test-results/test/binary",
        "${rootDir}/webapp/build/test-results/test/binary",
        "${rootDir}/webservice/build/test-results/test/binary")
}
```

root\batch\build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'java-common'
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(":common")
}
```

root\common\build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'java-common'
    id 'java-library'
}

dependencies {
    // Spring
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    api 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'
}
```

root\webapp\build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'java-common'
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(":common")
}
```

root\webservice\build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'java-common'
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(":common")
}
```

We changed the setting of Test Report output as follows, the Test Report is no longer output.

```
test {
    // Test Result Reports are output from all projects at once.
    reports.html.required = false

    // add this property
    tasks.test.binaryResultsDirectory = file("${rootDir}/build/test-results/test/binary")
}

// Create a Test Result Report
// gradlew testReport
task testReport(type: TestReport) {
    destinationDirectory = file("${rootDir}/build/reports/allTests")
    // reportOn files("${rootDir}/batch/build/test-results/test/binary",
    //     "${rootDir}/common/build/test-results/test/binary",
    //     "${rootDir}/webapp/build/test-results/test/binary",
    //     "${rootDir}/webservice/build/test-results/test/binary")
}
```

In the implementation of [Gradle's TestReport class](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/testing-jvm/src/main/java/org/gradle/api/tasks/testing/TestReport.java), we also checked what goes into the "testResults" property of the testReport task.

On top of this, we have implemented the modifications to the above configuration.
What configuration modification should we try next?

Answer (score 0):

We resolved this problem to use [The Test Report Aggregation Plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/7.5.1/userguide/test_report_aggregation_plugin.html).
The plugin's setting is below.

root\build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'eclipse'
    id 'project-report'
    id 'test-report-aggregation'
}

dependencies {
    testReportAggregation project(':common')
    testReportAggregation project(':batch')
    testReportAggregation project(':webapp')
    testReportAggregation project(':webservice')
}

reporting {
    reports {
        testAggregateTestReport(AggregateTestReport) { 
            testType = TestSuiteType.UNIT_TEST
        }
    }
}
```

root\buildSrc\src\main\groovy\java-common.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'eclipse'
    id 'project-report'
    id 'org.springframework.boot'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management'
}

sourceCompatibility = 17
targetCompatibility = 17

[compileJava, compileTestJava]*.options*.encoding = "UTF-8"

group = 'com.example'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
    testCompileOnly {
        extendsFrom testAnnotationProcessor
    }
}

dependencies {
    // Spring
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    
    // Apache Commons Lang3
    implementation "org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.12.0"
    
    // lombok
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testCompileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testAnnotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'

    // JUnit
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.9.1'
    
    // Mockito
    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:4.8.1'
    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-inline:4.8.1'
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()

    testLogging {
        showStandardStreams false
        events 'failed'
        exceptionFormat 'full'
    }
    systemProperty "file.encoding", "UTF-8"
    jvmArgs = ['--add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED']
}

test {
    // Test Result Reports are output from all projects at once.
    reports.html.required = false
}

// Delete this task!!!
// Create a Test Result Report
// gradlew testReport
// task testReport(type: TestReport) {
//    destinationDirectory = file("${rootDir}/build/reports/allTests")
//    reportOn files("${rootDir}/batch/build/test-results/test/binary",
//        "${rootDir}/common/build/test-results/test/binary",
//        "${rootDir}/webapp/build/test-results/test/binary",
//        "${rootDir}/webservice/build/test-results/test/binary")
}
```

After setting, we execute this command.

```
gradlew testAggregateTestReport
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this page：
https://docs.gradle.org/7.5.1/userguide/java_testing.html#test_reporting

root\build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'eclipse'
}

configurations {
    testReportData {
        canBeResolved = true
        canBeConsumed = false
        attributes {
            attribute(Category.CATEGORY_ATTRIBUTE, objects.named(Category, Category.DOCUMENTATION))
            attribute(DocsType.DOCS_TYPE_ATTRIBUTE, objects.named(DocsType, 'test-report-data'))
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    testReportData project(':common')
    testReportData project(':batch')
    testReportData project(':webapp')
    testReportData project(':webservice')
}

tasks.register('testReport', TestReport) {
    destinationDirectory = reporting.baseDirectory.dir('allTests')
    testResults.from(configurations.testReportData)
}
```

root\buildSrc\src\main\groovy\java-common.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'eclipse'
    id 'project-report'
    id 'org.springframework.boot'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management'
}

sourceCompatibility = 17
targetCompatibility = 17

[compileJava, compileTestJava]*.options*.encoding = "UTF-8"

group = 'com.example'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
    testCompileOnly {
        extendsFrom testAnnotationProcessor
    }
}

dependencies {
    // Spring
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    
    // Apache Commons Lang3
    implementation "org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.12.0"
    
    // lombok
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testCompileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testAnnotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'

    // JUnit
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.9.1'
    
    // Mockito
    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:4.8.1'
    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-inline:4.8.1'
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()

    testLogging {
        showStandardStreams false
        events 'failed'
        exceptionFormat 'full'
    }
    systemProperty "file.encoding", "UTF-8"
    jvmArgs = ['--add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED']
}

test {
    // Test Result Reports are output from all projects at once.
    reports.html.required = false
}

// ↓add setting
configurations {
    binaryTestResultsElements {
        canBeResolved = false
        canBeConsumed = true
        attributes {
            attribute(Category.CATEGORY_ATTRIBUTE, objects.named(Category, Category.DOCUMENTATION))
            attribute(DocsType.DOCS_TYPE_ATTRIBUTE, objects.named(DocsType, 'test-report-data'))
        }
        outgoing.artifact(test.binaryResultsDirectory)
    }
}

// Delete this task!!!
// Create a Test Result Report
// gradlew testReport
// task testReport(type: TestReport) {
//    destinationDirectory = file("${rootDir}/build/reports/allTests")
//    reportOn files("${rootDir}/batch/build/test-results/test/binary",
//        "${rootDir}/common/build/test-results/test/binary",
//        "${rootDir}/webapp/build/test-results/test/binary",
//        "${rootDir}/webservice/build/test-results/test/binary")
}
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34770841)